# JDBC with HBase?

Tags: java, jdbc, hadoop, hdfs

As I want to store data on HDFS, so need to access the HBase, so how could I connect to HBase using Java APIs.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HBase has Java API. Have a look at http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/index.html

Two important classes are

1) HBaseAdmin 
2) HTable

HBaseAdmin is admin API used to create/delete/alter tables 
HTable is the client API used to put/get/scan records.

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple framework to operate on hbase.
https://github.com/zhang-xzhi/simplehbase/

Simplehbase is a lightweight ORM framework between java app and hbase.
The main feature of it are following:

- data type mapping: mapping java type to hbase's bytes back and forth.
- hbase operation wrapping: warpping hbase's put get scan operation to simple java interface.
- hbase query language: using hbase filter, simplehbase can use sql-like style to operate on hbase.
- dynamic query: like myibatis, simplehbase can use xml config file to define dynamic query to operate on hbase.
- insert update support: provide insert, update on top of checkAndPut.
- multiple version support: provide interface to operation on hbase's multiple version.
- hbase batch operation support.
- hbase native interface support.
- HTablePool management.
- HTable count and sum.

Answer (score 0):

Use HBase as source using using TableMapper class and store in hdfs